# Replacing NAs in column with values from another table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update, inner-join

This is my first time posting to stack overflow and I know that similar questions have been asked before, so I apologize in advance. However, I can't seem to work around this regardless of solutions given in other forums.

I have two tables in SQL Server, one contains storm event info and the other contains county info. They both contain identical `county_fips` numbers. Neither of these contain primary or foreign keys.

I need to replace the NAs from the storm event info with the lat/lons from the county table. Is this possible without foreign/primary key relationships?

The `StormEvent` table looks like this:

```
ID | Lat | Lon | State_FIPS | County_FIPS 
------------------------------------------
1  |  33 | -88 |    028     |    087
2  |  31 | -98 |    048     |    225
3  |  NA |  NA |    017     |    034
4  | 39  | -100|    020     |    063
```

and so on...

The `CountyTable` looks like this (statefp10, countyfp10 = FIPS; intptlat10, intptlon10 = lat/lon):

```
  StateFP10 | County_FP10   | State_FP10| intptlat10 | intptlon10
   --------------------------------------------------------------
    1       |  087          | 028       |    33      |  -88
    2       |  225          | 048       |    31      |  -98     
    3       |  034          | 017       |    45      |  -102
```

And so on.

So far I've tried the following code to adjust the Lat column with slight variations:

```
UPDATE n 
SET n.lat= c.intptlat10
FROM StormEvent n 
INNER JOIN CountyTable c ON n.County_FIPS= c.CountyFP10
WHERE n.LAT = 'NA'
```

The query is executed, and I'm told x amount of rows were affected, but when I write a select statement to retrieve all of the NAs included in the Lats for the `StormEvent` table, they are still there.

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated! Again, I apologize if I am going about this the wrong way, this is my first post and I am a SQL novice.

Comment: i think the `SET` has incorrect column-name. Should it be `n.LAT= . . .`?

Comment: Do you actually need to set the values, or do you just need to see data there when you query?

Comment: I do need to set the values, eventually have to export this table back to R.

Comment: set does have an incorrect column name, that was an error just in this forum... Thanks! I have to update my question

Comment: Can you export the results of a query?

Comment: I'm a beginner, so correct me if I'm wrong because I very well could be. The plan was to use a query to edit the table through a query, not just display results from one. So, I wanted to replace all of the NAs in the table permanently, not just through a select statement. Then once the table is edited I would export it back to R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just need to update your `JOIN`. I've created some table variables to test with.

```
DECLARE @StormEvent TABLE (ID INT, Lat VARCHAR(10), Lon VARCHAR(10), 
                            State_FIPS INT, County_FIPS INT)
INSERT @StormEvent (ID , Lat, Lon, State_FIPS, County_FIPS)
VALUES  (1,'33','-88',028,087),
        (2,'31','-98',048,225),
        (3,'NA','NA',017,034),
        (4,'39','-100',020,063)


DECLARE @CountyTable TABLE (StateFP10 INT, County_FP10   INT, State_FP10 INT, 
                            intptlat10 VARCHAR(10), intptlon10 VARCHAR(10))
INSERT @CountyTable
VALUES  (1,087,028,'33','-88'),
        (2,225,048,'31','-98'),
        (3,034,017,'45','-102')

UPDATE n 
SET n.lat= c.intptlat10, n.Lon = c.intptlon10
FROM @StormEvent n 
INNER JOIN @CountyTable c ON n.State_FIPS= c.State_FP10
WHERE n.LAT = 'NA'

SELECT *
FROM @StormEvent
```

Assuming you want both `N/A` values updated, just add the `Lon` column to your `UPDATE`.

```
SET n.Lat = c.intptlat10, n.Lon = c.intptlon10
```

Results:

```
ID  Lat Lon     State_FIPS   County_FIPS
1   33  -88     28           87
2   31  -98     48           225
3   45  -102    17           34
4   39  -100    20           63
```

Comment: That was a typo in the question, my fault! However, I used your suggestion of a full outer join and it worked!! I'm double checking everything now, but it looks good so far.

Comment: Can you explain why you think the FULL OUTER join is necessary? Your code seems to perform identically without it.

Comment: @beercohol, that's just what I used when I was testing the query and OP seemed to like it. I'm wondering if there was actually some other difference between the query that was initially typed and this one.

Comment: So, I was incorrect. The NAs were no longer there because they were filled in with NULLS. I'm not sure why it can't get the values from the other table.

Comment: @awal23 The above query works fine with the sample data provided. Is there something more to the problem?

Comment: @bjones - Operator error. The values I needed to import were also missing from the county table due to an error while importing. Sorry! (Beginner) Your answer got me on the right track, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't actually need to set the data, but you just want to see lat/lon data when you query, you should be able to do something like this:

```
select 
a.ID, 
case a.Lat when 'NA' then b.intptlat10 else a.Lat end as Lat, 
case a.Lon when 'NA' then b.intptlon10 else a.Lon end as Lon, 
a.State_FIPS, 
a.County_FIPS 
from StormEvent a
left join CountyTable b
on a.State_FIPS = b.StateFIPS;
```